# PhoneGap App packaging steps: targeting offline use?

Tags: cordova

I have a jQuery Mobile app that I've put together with Phone Gap Build in mind.  It's online at [www.lcbobuddy.com](http://www.lcbobuddy.com).  I'm making some assumptions about best practices as I approach the point where I want to release my first version, and I thought I'd ask :

**What are the steps that one should use when packaging a website for Phone Gap Build?**

I assume the below, corrections, edits, additions welcome.

- Move any CDN based resources to local versions: jQuery mobile, Knockout, jQuery, other frameworks
- Set up a static local version of any data sets that would normally come from remote API urls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, move any CDN based resources to local versions: jQuery mobile, Knockout, jQuery, other frameworks. All html, js files will be served locally from the app.
Use something like http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/ 
to store data sets in local db and use it and refresh it on making ajax calls.

Make sure the  app is usable in airplane mode. i.e., it can work with the data in the local db and show proper error msgs whr data is not available from db.

Comment: Thanks for the Lawnchair tip, seems about right. I'm just raw localStorage at the moment, it looks like an improvement.